# How Fast Can You Put Together A Demo?

Tags: rad, demo

---

Edit:

**Seriously**, what's the problem with this question? If someone convinces me, I'll take it down myself.

---

Regardless of libraries, tools, skeleton apps .. How fast can you put together a Demo?

Last night I commented on "What RAD tools are out there?" ([What RAD tools are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510664/what-rad-tools-are-out-there/511965#511965)).

Two hours later I'd gotten this done, http://125.214.67.190:5824/.

This is not a brag session. I validly want to know how fast other Devs, using other tools, can put together Demos.

---

Edit:

Here's the really REALLY simple db, the important files:

http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/1597851/M.jpg.

It's almost too simple Hogan.

Comment: Voting to close as 'not-a-real-question'.

Comment: Huh? How is this not a real development question?

Comment: Thanks gbrant. Glad to hear I'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your example is not very aesthetically pleasing. So I didn't bother looking at it very long.

Why? Because if you are going to do demo something, do something *interesting*. You have to capture people's attention. So rather than some web page that fronts a db, give me a use-case I can sink my teeth into.

This is why being able to whip up a demo quickly is not all that useful in and of itself (IMO). The hard part of an app isn't the execution of the idea, it's the idea itself and the refinement of it that is the long pole.

Comment: Are you serious? Did you read the Question link? The whole idea was to model a problem posed by the Questioner. 

Web aesthetics can be put together afterwards. CSS and a good graphic designer. But you gotta get the foundation right first.

Comment: I disagree. Design IS the app, not something that can be slapped on as an afterthought.

Comment: I agree to an extent. You definitely have to have an awareness of "where things go". But if I am putting together a demo and would need to sink say 5 hours into learning how to implement JQuery to give a "nice" UI, and it's already 3am, I'm gonna be okay with NOT doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Borland C++ Builder or Borland Delphi

The rad tools in Borland tools are extensive and very easy to learn and use.

I would say a couple of hours with someone familiar with the tools would not be a problem.

I would also suggest that any rad tool worth its salt should do the job in a few hours, its just a demo!

While I'm at it, be careful how good your demos look, always leave something missing or something out of place. To most users a good looking demo means that the program is 80% done!

Comment: Agreed. Familiarity with a good RAD tool can mean awesome productivity.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the kind and the size of the demo. if it is work related and my boss is breathing behind my neck than usually about a week otherwise about a month.